# Wordpress: Conditional function (if/else) for custom tag

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using a custom type tag named "price_tag" that to display the list of them, I use this :

```
<?php if(get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'price_tag')) echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'price_tag', '', ' - ', '' ); else echo __('No Tags', 'custom-lang'); ?>
```

What I want is to create a condition using the "price_tag" to display a text if the post has a certain " price_tag"

so I wanted to try this

```
<? if ( has_tag ('certaintag' ) ) { ?>
Show something
<? } else {} ?>
```

"cetainbtag" is just a tag that I want to use to show a text in all posts that have that tag.

But I cannot get it to work and as I am not wordpress techie , I dont know how to include the " price_tag " to this conditional.

Please help. I be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordpress's `wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);` to get all the tags of the post it will return the array and you have to loop through the array to get the tags

```
$tags=wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
$alltags=array();
foreach($tags as $t){
$alltags[]=$t->taxonomy;
}
```

Then use `inarray` in you if condition

```
if (in_array("certaintag", $alltags)) {
 Show something
}else{

}
```

Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of `has_tag` is

```
has_tag( $tag, $post );
```

If you are in the loop then you can use

```
if( has_tag( 'price_tag' ) ) {
    // price_tag exists, do your job here
}
```

Above code will check, if current `post` has `price_tag` tag attached to it, you can also pass an array for multiple tags, i.e.

```
if( has_tag( array('price_tag', 'another_tag') ) ) {
    // ...
}
```

If you want to check whether `price_tag` exists from outside of the loop then you can use

```
if( has_tag( 'price_tag', $post ) ) {
    // price_tag exists, do your job here
}
```

In this case `$post` is the `$post` object that you've queried. Look at [has_tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_tag) on `Codex` and this [post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-has_tag-to-display-certain-information?replies=8) on `WordPress forum` too.

You can also use [has_term( $term, $taxonomy, $post )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term), i.e.

```
if( has_term( 'price_tag', 'post_tag' ) ) {
    // do something
}
```

Also, [term_exists( $term, $taxonomy, $parent )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists) could be used as given below

```
$term = term_exists( 'price_tag', 'post_tag' );
if ( $term !== 0 && $term !== null ) {
    // The term 'price_tag' is used as a post tag;
}
```

Above code will return the `id` of the term (`price_tag` in this case) if it exists.

Also check [get_the_tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) and [get_tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags) on `Codex` and these WordPress answers ([this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76291/custom-text-for-certain-tags) and [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31970/verify-if-tag-is-used-on-posts)) too, hope you can find a solution from anyone of these.

Comment: Thanks alot Sheikh Heera for the answer.. but I am afraid my question was not clear enough.

I have a custom type tag that's named price_tag, it's linked to a custom type post, not the default one, and I want to display a text when that price_ tag returns to a certain value . for me, I tried this approach:

If price_tag = certaintag => Disply text
Else => Display nothing.

When I used this , it didnt work :( 
<? if ( has_tag ('certaintag' ) ) { ?>
Show something
<? } else {} ?>
Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I use Dianaj's approach but with some syntax changes:

```
$tags = get_the_tags($post->ID);
if ($tags) {
  foreach ($tags as $t) {
   $tag_array[] = $t->slug;
  }
 if (in_array('certaintag',$tag_array)) {
  //Do something
 } else {
  //Do something else
 }
}
```

If you put this snippet inside a function, don't forget to add `global $post;` before the first line of code. Also note I use the tag's slug rather than name. I find slugs are easier to use in conditionals than the tag name.

Comment: Thanks jdp, I will give it a try.
Unfortunatelyn Dianaj's did not work :(, Thanks to you all guys.